# Is there any group structure on the upper half plane?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I was told that the upper half plane has a purely group theoretic description
$$
\mathcal{H}\cong\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})/\text{SO}_2(\mathbb{R})
$$

I tried to construct a group homomorphism to prove it:

$$
\varphi:\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow\mathcal{H}
$$

by
$$
\gamma\mapsto\gamma(i)
$$

Because $\text{SO}_2(\mathbb{R})$ fixes $i$.

But unfortunately I cannot come out a group structure on $\mathcal{H}$ making $i$ the unit.

So can anyone help?

Comment: That "isomorphism" is as manifolds (or as manifolds-with-a-$SL_2(\mathbb R)$-action), not as groups in any sense.

Comment: Also, notice that $SO_2(\mathbb R)$ is not a normal subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb R)$!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The open half plane is diffeomorphic to the plane, so it has a Lie group structure isomorphic to that of $\mathbb R^2$.

There is another, which turns it into a Lie group isomorphic to connected component of the identity in the affine group on the line, also known as $\mathbb R\rtimes\mathbb R_{>0}$.

In fact, these are *all* Lie group structures in the upper half plane, up to isomorphism. Indeed, the Lie algebra corresponding to such a Lie group is of dimension $2$, and there are two real Lie algebras of dimension $2$. Since there are as many real Lie algebras of a given dimension as there are simply connected Lie groups of that dimension, we have the result.

Comment: Oh...It is far beyond what I know. Anyway, thank you!